# Adding navigation and footer to every page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new at Angular and trying to build a static website using angular and bootstrap. This is what I have done so far to create navigation (and footer using same method) to add to every pages in the website. Is there any better(more efficient) way building templates with Angular? Is this what everyone does for these type of applications?

```js
app.directive("mynav", function () {
 return {
  restrict: "A",
  template: "<nav class='navbar navbar-default' role='navigation'><div class='navbar-inner'><div class='container-fluid'><div class='navbar-header'><button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#menu-nav'><span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span><span class='icon-bar'></span><span class='icon-bar'></span><span class='icon-bar'></span></button><a class='navbar-brand' href='#'><img alt='img' src='img/logo.svg' height='30'></a></div><div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='menu-nav'><ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'><li><a href='pages/home.html'>Home</a></li><li><a href='pages/about.html'>About</a></li><li><a href='pages/service.html'>Services</a></li><li><a href='pages/product.html'>Rental Products</a></li><li><a href='pages/contact.html'>Contact</a></li><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary navbar-btn'>Request A Quote</button></ul></div></div></div></nav>"
 }
});
```

```html
<header mynav></header>
```

Comment: Is your navigation and footer fixed for all the pages?

Comment: @AniketSinha yet it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case your navbar is also static like footer, you can exclude it from ng-view

Your html structure can be something like :

`<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
   <div mynav></div>
   <div ng-view></div>
   <div my-footer></div>
</body>
</html>`

In this case, the navigation bar will be static too just like your footer. So all your views will be loaded at `<div ng-view></div>` and `mynav` and `my-footer` div will be untouched.

Also,In your directives, you can replace inline `template` with `templateUrl`. Create a new HTML, say `my-nav.html` and use `templateUrl: "path/to/my-nav.html"`,

Answer (score 3):

You dont need a directive for static html.

Usually you have a **shell page** (main page), in which you put all the parts that should be on all (or most) pages. And then you load you views into that page using angular's **ng-view** (or ui-view if you use ui-router for routing).

Something like this:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="navbarCtrl as vm">
           <div ng-include="'navbar.html'"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Your main view loads here, along with its controller 
             as defined in your routing (check ngRoute or ui-router for more)-->
        <div ng-view></div>

        <footer>Your footer comes here (or can be ng-included)</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at custom directives at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

And your directive will be like this:

```
app.directive('name', function() {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'page-title'.html
}
```

This is a better way, not only more tidy, it's also rendering faster.
I learn this at free course on schoolcode that pointed out from angular website.

*Note: by rendering time I mean `ng-include` will be loaded after javascript and html are all loded.*